# Facebook Graph API post to group fails with prod app but works in test app

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have been developing an app to post to a clients Page or Group

I have been using the test version of the app and have successfully posted to both a users group and page after the user authorizes my app via facebook login.

The app just went through the approval process and has been approved, so now i am testing the real app.

Using the Real app creds, i can post successfully to the users page, but when i try to post to the same group i have been posting to with the test app, i get the error

```
status-->403 error={\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#200) If posting to a group, requires app 
being installed in the group, and \\\\\\n          either publish_to_groups permission with 
user token, or both pages_read_engagement \\\\\\n          and pages_manage_posts permission 
with page token; If posting to a page, \\\\\\n          requires both pages_read_engagement 
and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \\\\\\n          sufficient administrative 
permission\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":200
```

These are the permissions i have

```
email, 
pages_show_list, 
publish_to_groups, 
groups_access_member_info, 
pages_read_engagement, 
pages_manage_posts, 
public_profile
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: `requires app being installed in the group` - that the case?

Comment: @CBroe thanks again, from what i can tell they must do this from FB correct? no way to do this via any api?

Comment: Yeah, I think that needs to happen manually, there is no API for that step.

Comment: @CBroe how is it possible to install the app to the group if the app doesnt appears on the list?

Comment: @Sophie I am not sure, the documentation doesn't say anything explicitly about this, as far as I can tel. I suppose it might depend on the correct "circumstances" - app admin and group admin being the same account, is the first thing I would try.

Comment: Well that's primary, but tell me, did you already posted anything to a Facebook group using the API?